# PRESTASHOP Cannot connect to db: Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]

Tags: database, prestashop-1.7, lampp

I've created a PrestaShop 1.7.5 app on my server and everything works there.

I was trying to create my dev version, so I copied all files from server to my localhost.

I run my app using lampp.

Dev version doesn't work, because I got:

```
    Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'srv38468_pr1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at line 136 in file classes/db/DbPDO.php
```

I checked app/config/parameters.php:

```
    'database_host' => 'localhost',
'database_port' => '',
'database_name' => 'srv38468_pr1',
'database_user' => 'srv38468_pr1',
'database_password' => '****************',
'database_prefix' => 'pr_',
'database_engine' => 'InnoDB',
```

and this is a db's config from my server:

[image]

I see this error is very popular but I've checked all solutions and nothing works.

Does anyone have any ideas, how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Double check db credentials,
as error states clearly that they are wrong.

If you are sure they are correct,
you might have old "production" cache
that can lead to a non reachable db.

I would suggest you to clear your /var/cache/*
folder and check back afterwards.